# Printing the content of an email marketing

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have created an email marketing. 
A different HTML with styles inline and all good practices of email marketing creation (that are very different from usual web development practices).

After struggling a little bit with this, I had a good html to be sent by email.

One problem, though... The people that receive the email will have to print its content and bring it back to me.

The best way I found was to select the content of the email and print it, but the content loses its styles, colors, etc.

I would like to know if there's a better way to print the email content. Maybe a link with some css... I really don't know.

As I didn't find clear info on this subject on the web, any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email design is hard enough without trying to make it print friendly as well. If the need to print is common practice for you, I would suggest including a hyperlink somewhere in your email to a web hosted version that is print friendly.

If it is something like a coupon they are printing, you could also take that opportunity to customize it more, add the fine print or any other info you'd like to omit from the email itself.

Comment: +1 I would add that even linking to a PDF file would be a good move as well and allow for consistency when printing.

Comment: Even better. The PDF route would make everyone's job a lot easier, unless you have anything dynamic in there, which would take more setup to convert it realtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! In my case its a coupon. I think the best options is the one John has listed, because, in the near future, I will have to put a link in the email to redirect to a webpage, when the user can't see the content. That could be the same page used for printing the content. Any problems passing the coupon's number through the URL? (maybe I'll have to encrypt it)

Comment: You could easily pass the users email address and do a lookup afterwards if you don't want the code in there. Most email service providers like Mailchimp or Campaign Monitor automatically create "web versions" of your email, and will carry across any merge tags (dynamic content specific to the recipient). Not sure how they would print however because they will have the exact same html code as the email.